# How to use Subprocess in Windows

Tags: python, windows, subprocess, pipe

I am trying to save the result or function *runcmd* in the variable *Result*.
Here is what I have tried: 
    import subprocess

```
def runcmd(cmd):
  x = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
  Result = x.communicate(stdout)
  return Result
runcmd("dir")
```

When I run ths code, I get this result:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\MyPython\MyCode.py", line 7, in <module>
    runcmd("dir")
  File "C:\Python27\MyPython\MyCode.py", line 4, in runcmd
    x = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 679, in __init__
errread, errwrite)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 893, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

What could I do to fix this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is os.listdir()

check out the [os module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os) for more info

an example:

```
>>> import os
>>> l = os.listdir()
>>> print (l)
['DLLs', 'Doc', 'google-python-exercises', 'include', 'Lib', 'libs', 'LICENSE.txt', 'NEWS.txt', 'python.exe', 'pythonw.e
xe', 'README.txt', 'tcl', 'Tools', 'VS2010Cmd.lnk']
>>>
```

You could also read the output into a list:

```
result = []
process = subprocess.Popen('dir', 
    shell=True, 
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE, 
    stderr=subprocess.PIPE )
for line in process.stdout:
    result.append(line)
errcode = process.returncode
for line in result:
    print(line)
```

Comment: if both `stderr` and `stdout` are `PIPE` then you should consume them concurrently to avoid blocking the subprocess. It doesn't matter for `dir` (it is unlikely that it generates so much output on `stderr`) but it is a bad practice in general. You could use `result = subprocess.check_output("dir", shell=True).splitlines()` instead.

Answer (score 14):

As far as I know, `dir` is a **built in command of the shell** in Windows and thus not a file available for execution as a program. Which is probably why `subprocess.Popen` cannot find it. But you can try adding `shell=True` to the `Popen()` construtor call like this:

```
def runcmd(cmd):
    x = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
    return x.communicate(stdout)

runcmd("dir")
```

If `shell=True` doesn't help, you're out of luck executing `dir` directly. But then you can make a `.bat` file and put a call to `dir` there instead, and then invoke that `.bat` file from Python instead.

btw also check out the [PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)!

**P.S** As Mark Ransom pointed out in a comment, you could just use `['cmd', '/c', 'dir']` as the value of `cmd` instead of the `.bat` hack if `shell=True` fails to fix the issue.

Comment: You could also use `["cmd", "/c", "dir"]` as the command if `shell=True` doesn't work.

Comment: @MarkRansom: probably a good idea—I'm not that familiar with Windows any more :)

Comment: you could also use `subprocess.check_output` here

Comment: @MarkRansom It's better to use `%COMSPEC%` instead of hardcoding `cmd` :)

Comment: How would `%COMSPEC%` be used?

Comment: @user2961646: `cmd = os.environ.get('COMSPEC', 'cmd')`?