# FileNotFoundError: The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to list the files present in the input folder:

```
from subprocess import check_output
print(check_output(["ls", "../input"]).decode("utf8"))
```

And I am getting this error (Using Python 3):

```
C:\Users\Tristan\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py in _execute_child(self, args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds, pass_fds, cwd, env, startupinfo, creationflags, shell, p2cread, p2cwrite, c2pread, c2pwrite, errread, errwrite, unused_restore_signals, unused_start_new_session)
    988                                          env,
    989                                          cwd,
--> 990                                          startupinfo)
    991             finally:
    992                 # Child is launched. Close the parent's copy of those pipe

FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ls` doesn't exist as a command in windows, hence the error; it can't find an executable named `ls` to run. The solutions to this similar question should help you do what you want: [How to use Subprocess in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19819417/how-to-use-subprocess-in-windows)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [Izaak Weiss](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5499871/izaak-weiss) answer, the solution becomes:

```
import os
l = os.listdir("input")
print (l)
```